# How to position nested divs like a table

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to create a sort-of table using divs and CSS. I got it to look right, but if I duplicate the table underneath, it does not line up right anymore.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="main_right">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="top_right">top right</div>
            <div class="top_left">top left</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="right">right1</div>
            <div class="left">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>left 1</td>
                        <td>left 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>left 1</td>
                        <td>left 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="right">right2</div>
            <div class="left">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>left 1</td>
                        <td>left 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>left 1</td>
                        <td>left 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_left">main left</div>
</div>
<br>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 800px;
}
.main_left {
    width:200px;
    background:red;
}
.main_right {
    float:right;
    width:600px;
}
.top_left {
    background:blue;
    width: 400px;
}
.top_right {
    background:purple;
    float: right;
    width:200px;
}
.left {
    background:yellow;
    width: 350px;
}
.right {
    background:green;
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mK9TQ/

I'm trying to get the second red "main left" to line up next to the second blue "top left". I want each "outer" div to be its own table so I can duplicate as many as I want in a vertical list with space in between.

What am I missing in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without floats now using [the `display:table` and related display types for elements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

The only differences is you'd need to change your data to match the row > column setup of tables, rather than what appears to be the column > row setup you have at the moment.

If you just want the three columns to position correctly you can use something like below to style each inner div as a column, within the outer div.

```
div.outer { display:table-row}
div.outer > div { display:table-cell}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `float:left;` to `.main_left` class, so it will work.

```
.main_left {
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
```

[Here is Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mK9TQ/2/)